# Is "be it as an" grammatically correct?

Tags: questions

My sentence is "Water lily has many uses. Be it as an ornamental or as a food source."
Is that acceptable? Please help! Thank you.

Comment: I answered your question as you are a newbie but generally you need to tell us why you think it's OK or not, or show some research.

Comment: @Lambie I'm new to this so I don't really know the system here yet. Can you please clarify your question about what I need to tell or not? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I know. This is the section to read here: https://ell.stackexchange.com/help It explains about asking questions.

Answer (score 2):

The first part is almost okay.  It would sound better to use the plural. There are other questions about the difference between "The lion is a large cat" and "Lions are large cats", when talking about the species in general.

The second part isn't a complete sentence, so you need to change the punctuation to a comma.  What you actually are doing is giving examples of the many uses, so just say "... many uses, for example as an ornament or a food source."

There is a problem of meaning. "Be it" or "Be they" are subjuctive and mean (roughly) "if it is..."  So do you mean:

> Water lilies have many uses, if they are an ornament or used as food."

If this is not what you mean, you should not use the "be they" construct. Instead use one of the many ways of listing examples:

- ..., for example ...
- ..., such as ...
- ..., particularly ...

Or list the examples in a new sentence

> ... many uses. Flower arrangers value their large blooms and showy seedcases and cooks use their roots to add crunch to stir-fries.

The "be it" construction is a subjunctive and it means "if ... or not" for example:

> Be it rain or shine, you can have fun at a Pontins holiday camp!"

This means "if it is raining or if the sun is shining...".  You don't mean "Water Lilies have many uses, if it is ornamental or if it is a food source", so the "be it.." construction is not what you should use.

Comment: My whole sentence is actually "In particular, Santa Cruz water lily has many uses. Be it as an ornamental or as a food-source." Is 'be it as an' okay or should I use different words? (I'll use the plural form. Thank you)

Comment: @Nick - "be it as an" is an OK phrase, but what James K is saying is that you can't use it alone like you're trying to do.  "Be it as an ornamental or as a food source" is not a complete sentence.

Comment: You should use different words, as described in my answer. You should use a comma, and "for example".

Comment: @stangdon But what if I swap them like "Be it as an ornament or as a food source, Water lilies have many uses." Would that be okay or not? Thanks.

Comment: No, because "be it" means "If it is". It doesn't mean "For example". You should use "for example" as described in my answer.

Comment: @James K Is it okay for me to ask for any alternative words to use for that kind of sentence though? I mean, I've ran out of words (lol) and it'll really help me a lot. Thanks.

Comment: I've edited.  "Be they" doesn't work here, and I hope my edit explains why.

Comment: @Lambie yes, I think that isn't the meaning that the OP wants. See my answer for why.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's fine. What isn't fine is the first part:

The water lily has many uses.

or

Water lilies have many uses.

I suggest:

**The water lily has many uses, be it as an ornament or as a food source.**

or

**Water lilies have many uses, be they as ornaments or as a food source.**

[by the way, I am not attesting here to the truth of the statement.]

Comment: Do people really eat water lilies?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Apparently, they do: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nymphaea